# keydown event not fired on ace editor

Tags: ace-editor

The ace editor prevent keydown events from being fired. I think it `preventDefault`.

How can i remove this prevention or bind to keydown event before the editor event is executed ?

Answer (score 5):

ace stops only the events it already handled, 
you can either use capturing event listener (editor.container.addEventListener("keydown", handler, true))
or use command handlers of ace

Update: to block ace commands only sometimes capturing event handler will work, but sometimes ace hashHandler is nicer than big switch over keycodes

```
HashHandler = require("ace/keyboard/hash_handler").HashHandler
var turn = 0
var h = new HashHandler([{
    bindKey: "Up",
    descr: "Block cursor movement smetimes",
    exec: function(ed){
        turn++
        if (turn % 2)
            return false // allow other ace commands to handle event
    }
}])
editor.keyBinding.addKeyboardHandler(h)
// editor.keyBinding.removeKeyboardHandler(h)
```

or more compact form

```
var h = new HashHandler()
h.bindKeys({"Up": function(ed){...}})
```

Comment: Thanks about that, it works just great but its not exactly what i want. I want to prevent the editor from going down to the next row in some cases, so i need to bind to the keydown event before the ace's one so i could stop it if it needed.

Comment: Thank you! In particular I was after that editor.container.addEventListener("keydown", handler, true) line. This was doing my head in. Thank you! :)

Answer (score 3):

I also wanted to be able to optionaly filter cursor key presses (and consume them in a popup instead of it). I was able to inject this functionality with the following code:

```
editor.keyBinding.origOnCommandKey = editor.keyBinding.onCommandKey;
editor.keyBinding.onCommandKey = function(e, hashId, keyCode) {
    if (...) { 
        this.origOnCommandKey(e, hashId, keyCode);
    }
}
```

keyCode 38 stands for cursor up, keyCode 40 for down and 13 for enter. If the original function is not called, Ace won't see this key presses. Unfortunately the return key is still consumed by Ace.

This may be prevented with a similar solution:

```
editor.keyBinding.origOnTextInput = editor.keyBinding.onTextInput;
editor.keyBinding.onTextInput = function(text) {
    if (...) {
        this.origOnTextInput(text);
    }
}
```

text is a newline in this case.